# JSONObject is not updated correctly

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am, updating the value in a JSONObject that is inside a JSONArray, when changing the value is updating in all the JSONArray. Does anybody know why?

```
 public static void uploadMediaWithThumbnail( final LeagueActivity.UploadingCallback call,
                                             final long leagueId,
                                             final JSONArray information, final JsonHttpResponseHandler handler) {


    final AtomicInteger receivedCount = new AtomicInteger();
    receivedCount.set(0);

    call.progressCall(10);

    getMediaUploadUrl(leagueId, information,  new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            try {
                call.progressCall(20);

                final JSONArray allData = response.getJSONArray("upload_data");
                AsyncHttpClient[] clients = new AsyncHttpClient[allData.length()*2];
                JSONArray jarr = information;

                for (int i = 0; i < allData.length(); i++ ) {
                    final String uploadUrl = allData.getJSONObject(i).getString("content_url");
                    final String previewUrl = allData.getJSONObject(i).getString("preview_url");

                    jarr.getJSONObject(i).put("content", uploadUrl);
                    jarr.getJSONObject(i).put("preview", previewUrl);

                }

                final JSONArray newInfo = shallowCopy(jarr);

                Log.d("Log1", newInfo.getJSONObject(1).getString("content"));

                Log.d("Log2", newInfo.getJSONObject(0).getString("content"));
```

When logging Log1 and Log2 they contain the same link

information is a data like this `[{"type":"video","format":"mp4","preview_format":"jpg"}, {"type":"video","format":"mp4","preview_format":"jpg"}]`

AllData is information received from an REST HTTP call and has the same length as information

Comment: information is a JSONArray with the data

Comment: Please post the complete code @David Vittori

Comment: It seems `information` is redundant with `allData` in its current form. If `information` is maintained locally, there is no reason to be dealing with it in JSON. It can be a normal data structure like a List or Array.

Comment: Well, allData is retrived from the server and information is going to be sent.

Comment: are you sure that `alldata` and `information` have the same length because you're parsing both inside one loop.

Comment: if information is being sent where else are you gathering information to send it? because theres a easy solution to this, but i want to make suer that you may or may not be getting anything for information somewhere else. bc then it could be tricky.

Comment: You would get this behavior if `information.getJSONObject(0)` and `information.getJSONObject(1)` were the same object.  Check how you populated the elements of `information`.

Comment: I updated the answer, I don't know why all the JSONObjects of the array are updated with the last one that i put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update.

You want to add the items for information into a JSONObject, and then add that object to your JSONArray.

```
    JSONArray jarr = information;

    for (int i = 0; i < allData.length(); i++ ) {
        final String uploadUrl = allData.getJSONObject(i).getString("content_url");
        final String previewUrl = allData.getJSONObject(i).getString("preview_url");

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("content", uploadUrl);
        object.put("preview", previewUrl);
        jarr.put(i, object);
    }
```

After the for loop, you can then get the values from the keys.

Or, if jarr already has objects...

```
    JSONArray jarr = information;

    for (int i = 0; i < allData.length(); i++ ) {
        final String uploadUrl = allData.getJSONObject(i).getString("content_url");
        final String previewUrl = allData.getJSONObject(i).getString("preview_url");

        JSONObject object = new jarr.getJSONObject(i);
        object.put("content", uploadUrl);
        object.put("preview", previewUrl);
        jarr.put(i, object);
    }
```

this isnt tested, but should work. haha

Comment: Thank you! I did something like this but I created a new JSONArray also and added everything there

Comment: @DavidVittori No problem if this helped answered your question, please accept. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
JSONArray jsonArray;
    try {
//here replace with your data object
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(" [{\"type\":\"video\",\"format\":\"mp4\",\"preview_format\":\"jpg\"}, {\"type\":\"video\",\"format\":\"mp4\",\"preview_format\":\"jpg\"}]");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            jsonObject.put("content", "test value " + i);
        }
        Log.d("Print test",  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).toString());
        Log.d("Print test",  jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).toString());
    } catch (
            JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to create a new JSONArray and Insert new JSONObject with the info inside it